# C++ std::forward<T> vs static_cast<T>

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

From what I understand, `std::forward<T>(x)` is equivalent to `static_cast<T&&>(x)`.

But from what I saw, `static_cast<T>(x)` seems to do the same thing, as can be seen in the following [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/414af690f258db96)

My question is therefore why `std::forward<T>` is implemented as `static_cast<T&&>(x)`, and not `static_cast<T>(x)`, if both have the same effect?

Comment: You didn't try with `int&`.

Comment: @Quentin In that case, it always returns an lvalue.

Comment: `static_cast<T>` would create a copy of rvalues

Comment: because you want to forward references but not values

Comment: Try it with a class where you will instrument the copy and move ctors to produce output, and observe the differences.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because perfect forwarding allows to pass both *r-value references* and *l-value references*. This is done via [reference collapsing](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers):

```
T = int    --> T&& = int&&
T = int&   --> T&& = int& && = int&
T = int&&  --> T&& = int&& && = int&&
```

In your example with `static_cast<T>` you're simply losing r-value references. It works fine for primitive types (because passing `int` is usually copying a CPU register value), but awful for complex types because it leads to creating temporary object through copy ctors.

Comment: I just checked it, and it is in fact calls the copy constructor for rvalue's.

But why? I read that if we call func() with an rvalue, T is deduced to be int&&, so static_cast<T>(x) would become static_cast<int&&>(x).

So why it creates a copy?

Comment: `static_cast<T>` can return a reference: the answer above implies it cannot.  Can you clarify that the problem only occurs in one "case"?

Comment: @Mikrosaft: no, `T` cannot be deduced to `int&&`, it only can be either `int` or `int&`.

Comment: @myaut It makes perfect sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If `T&&` is an rvalue reference, then `T` is a value, then `static_cast<T>` makes a *copy* not a rvalue reference.

That copy will bind to rvalue references (just like the reference), but copy/move ctors could be needlessly called, and it is not a candidate for elision.

`static_cast<T&&>` will meanwhile just cast to an rvalue reference.

They are otherwise identical.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Yakk, but it's worse than that.

```
void foo(const std::vector<int> &vec);

template<typename T>
void callFoo(T &&data)
{
    foo(static_cast<T>(data));
}

int main()
{
    callFoo(std::vector<int>{/*...*/});
}
```

This will always create a copy. The vector is *not* moved because `data`, as an expression, is an lvalue of type `std::vector<int>`, even though the substituted type is `std::vector<int>&&`. Note that `T` is `std::vector<int>`, not `std::vector<int> &&`. Moral of the story: Use the standard library, it does the right thing and the name `forward` also captures the intention far better than `static_cast<something>`.

Comment: Remark: when either [xvalue or prvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3601602/5267751) is used as the argument `T` is `std::vector<int>` and `T&&` (or `decltype(data)`) is `std::vector<int>&&`. So `static_cast<decltype(data)>(data)` can be used, which is occasionally useful, see e.g. 
 [c++ - Perfect forwarding in a lambda? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42799208/5267751)