# Why is this macro being passed three arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, stdinitializerlist

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo { int a, b, c; };

int main()
{
    Foo myFoo = Foo{ 1, 2, 3 };

    std::vector<Foo> listOfFoos;
    listOfFoos.push_back(Foo{ 1, 2, 3 });


#define push(x) listOfFoos.push_back(x)

    push(Foo{ 1, 2, 3 } ); // Error

}
```

Errors are:

```
> "Expected a '}'"  
> "Syntax error: expected a ')' not '}'"  "Syntax
> error: missing ')' before ';'"
```

It took me ages on Visual Studio to try to figure out what was happening. It wasn't until I compiled on an online compiler using GCC that I got a more descriptive error:

> error: macro "push" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 1

I guess I'm confused because I thought std::initializer_list is one struct, and should get passed as one. When it complains that 3 arguments as being passed to the macro is it saying by doing push({1, 2, 3}); I'm doing the equivalent of push(1, 2, 3);? This would seem that std::initializer_list does a type of expansion of its elements before the precompiler stage when it resolves the macro. I dont understand why this is. Also, I tried wrapping it in another set of brackets and it works:

```
push( ( {1, 2, 3} ) );
```

Comment: Your the structure declaration- `struct Foo { int a, b, c; };` is wrong. It should be `struct Foo { int a; int b; int c; };`

Comment: @H.S. Are you sure? Declarations like this or int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3; are perfectly fine outside classes, unless there's a special rule against these in classes...

Comment: Zebrafish : oops .. my bad, ignore my comment.

Comment: The whole comma thing is confusing to me too. There's a whole Wikipedia article about the C comma operator, and I only half get it, apparently it evaluates all the comma-separated expressions, but just returns the last one, so in one example, someone asked what the following loop did which seems to have two conditions: for(i=0; j>=0, i<=5; i++), the only condition is the second one i <= 5, the first one in this case does nothing, as a condition I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros are very primitive and limited, they do not (necessarily) know anything about the programming language they're used in.

Assume you have the macro

```
#define foo(x, y, z)
```

and use it like `foo(1, 2, 3)`. The preprocessor splits at the comma (`,`) and sets the variables `x`, `y`, and `z` accordingly to the input numbers. In your macro-call, `push(Foo{ 1, 2, 3 } )`, this is not different. It splits at the comma and sets `x` to `Foo{ 1`. However, there are two more values, `2` and `3 }`, hence the error. The curly braces are *not special in any way* for the preprocessor, its just another letter.

To just *pass everything through*, instead of taking one argument, take it as va-args:

```
#define push(...) listOfFoos.push_back(__VA_ARGS__)
```

where `...` means, *if there is anything extra, just take it* and `__VA_ARGS__` means *expand to everything you got extra*.

Hint: It's always nice to have a tab to [godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) with compiler flags set to `-E` open to check macro expansion. [Example](https://godbolt.org/g/eXbRpy)

Comment: It's strange, because seeing as though I see the macros as simply paste jobs in the preprocessor stage, I expected {1, 2, 3} to go through untouched.

Comment: @Zebrafish They are simple paste jobs, but not _that_ simple. They allow multiple parameters, so there has to be some way of splitting them. I'll post an workaround in a sec

Comment: That's OK, unless you have a better way, as I mentioned if I wrap them in another set of brackets it works fine. It's not as if I intend to use this, I was just experimenting and trying to find the better way shorten the code, but I was surprised when this happened.

Comment: @Zebrafish I've edited my answer, passing through va-args works. Or in a simple case like this, even `#define push listOfFoos.push_back` would do the job.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could do that. That's nice.

Comment: I'm guessing __VA_ARGS__ is a macro-specific term?

Comment: I guess what I'm not understanding is why push(Foo{1, 2, 3}) is considered 3 arguments. And also by passing Foo{1, 2, 3} to push(...) listOfFoos.push_back(__VA_ARGS__); what does the it look like after macro expansion? Just as I typed it? Foo{1, 2, 3}?

Comment: `push(Foo{1, 2, 3})` is considered 3 arguments because the preprocessor primitively splits at the `,`, ignoring the curly braces. You can check macro-espansion by compiling with the `-E` flag, for example: https://godbolt.org/g/SzgpPF (the output window in the middle shows the result)

Comment: I see, so doing it as just #define push listOfFoos.pushback instead of #define push(x) listOfFoos.pushback(x) works. OK, thanks.

Comment: You could also use a lambda. `auto push = [&](auto&& x) { listOfFoos.push_back(x); };`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I might be wrong, but I think you need an `std::forward<decltype(x)>` there to perfectly forward ([Perfect forwarding in a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799208/perfect-forwarding-in-a-lambda))

Comment: `push((Foo{1,2,3}))` would also have worked, but the argument is then `(Foo{1,2,3})`, which is OK in this particular case. That works because the preprocessor does not split on commas *inside parentheses*. (Only parentheses. Neither brackets nor braces protect commas.)