# Perfect forwarding a value of type auto

Tags: c++, function, parameters, auto, forward

How can we forward a function auto parameter using std::forward for the below code?

```
void push_value(std::vector<MyType>& vec, auto&& value)
{
    vec.emplace_back(std::forward<?>(value));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `decltype(value)(value)` (without `forward`).

Some prefer to write `std::forward<decltype(value)>(value)`, but it does exactly the same thing, the `forward` is superfluous.

Comment: While `decltype(value)(value)` is a neat trick, it doesn't really help with clarity/declaring intent. Opposed to `std::forward`ing, it will also result in a copy instead of a move when changing `auto&&` to `auto`. More info about it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799658/7107236).

Comment: @303 The answer you linked to states they prefer `decltype(x)(x)`. :P I agree that `std::forward` is harder to break unintentionally, but I wouldn't use it for a non-reference intentionally (it should be `std::move`).