# A function that takes a predicate as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++20

There is an answer explaining [why std::find_if takes a predicate by value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48803986/2394762).

But what if I define my own function that takes a predicate as a parameter?

For example, consider the following functions that calls a given function for each tuple element:

```
template <typename... Args, typename Func, std::size_t... index>
constexpr void for_each(const std::tuple<Args...>& t, Func&& f, std::index_sequence<index...>)
{
    (f(std::get<index>(t)), ...);
}

template <typename... Args, typename Func>
constexpr void for_each(const std::tuple<Args...>& t, Func&& f)
{
    for_each(t, f, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}
```

in this code `f` is passed by rvalue-reference, it is a right way?

Sample usage:

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(5, std::string(""));

for_each(t, [](auto& field)
{
    std::cout << field << std::endl;
});
```

Should not there be `const Func&`?

Comment: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15673889/4688321) question.

Comment: "*in this code f is passed by rvalue-reference.*" No. The second `for_each` overload passes the *lvalue* `f` into the first overload, so the `Func` of the first overload is always an lvalue type.

Comment: `T&&` is not an rvalue reference  when `T` is a template parameter.

Comment: [OT]: Can be rewritten `std::apply([&](auto&&... args){ (f(args), ...)}, t);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 is `auto&&... args` a forwarding reference ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Probably it can be `std::apply([&](auto&&... args) { (f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)), ...); }, t);` or simply `std::apply([&](auto&... args) { (f(args), ...); }, t);` with a single `&`, because `args` are lvalues.

Comment: @Jarod42 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799208/perfect-forwarding-in-a-lambda (The canonical way to forward a lambda argument that was bound to a forwarding reference is indeed with decltype)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in this code f is passed by rvalue-reference

It's actually passed by a "forwarding reference".

> it is a right way?

Yes, that's fine if you expect people will pass in complicated objects that are expensive to copy. I would also default to that.

Comment: My understanding is that according to forwarding refences concepts there should be `std::forward` in the second overload. Another question is that it probably would not affect the generated code.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky `std::forward` is only relevant when you're actually forwarding this object somewhere (passing as an argument, assigning to some other variable, etc). There is no point in using `std::forward` just to call the function.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky If you want to learn about forwarding references, you can refer to this article: https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili  If I do not `std::forward` in the second overload then it does not make a sense to declare the first overload with parameter `f` as forwarding reference, then I simply declare it as `const Func&`

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky People usually default to forwarding references because it's usually correct and almost never wrong. For example, passing it as a const reference limits the flexibility (can't use a mutable `operator()` anymore), so technically you want it as a regular reference which becomes const or non const depending on the object passed.

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili probably I understand what you mean, but I still think that this `for_each(t, std::forward<Func>(f), std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});` is a better coding style in the second overload. Probably it is also better to default to `std::forward` just in case if a calling function assigns `f` so some internal variable, for example, like `Func temp = std::forward<Func>(f);` and uses `std::forward` in its turn.

Comment: And if you change your mind and decide to actually forward the callable object somewhere, you can do it without breaking the ABI.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky oh, yeah, that second overload should definitely use `std::forward`. I missed that part.